# Value goes in the database, but doesn't show up in the view - Symfony3

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a project related to restaurants.
I have an entity `restaurant` with several fields, and a foreign key related to another entity called `people`

Once I created the restaurant page with its form, and can view the `restaurant` in its view (show.html.twig), I should be able to click on a link that lets me add a value for `how many people can eat there`
This should open a new page, with a little form where I can add this value. Once submitted, I should be redirected to the restaurant page (show.html.twig) and then see the value which I just entered.

**The FormType I created to add the number of people**

```
    class PeopleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('value', NumberType::class, array(
                'label'             => 'How many people',
                'required'          => false,
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label'             => 'submit'
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => People::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

**and I created a specific controller for that**

```
    class PeopleController extends Controller
{
    public function PeopleAction(Request $request, Restaurant $restaurant)
    {
        $people = new People();
        $form = $this->createForm(PeopleType::class, $people);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($people);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_restaurant_show', array('id' => $restaurant->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('admin/restaurant/people.html.twig', array(
            'restaurant'    => $restaurant,
            'form'          => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

**and the route I created**

```
admin_restaurant_people:
    path:    /{id}/people
    defaults: { _controller: "AdminBundle:Retrocession:people" }
```

**in my restaurant view(show.html.twig) where I already added a restaurant with a form. I have the link to the route going to my `PeopleType` form view**

```
<a href="{{ path('admin_restaurant_people', { 'id': restaurant.id }) }}">Add people</a>
```

So once on this page I can add my value, and then redirect to the restaurant page `show.html.twig` when clicking on submit

[image]

And then to be able to display the value in the restaurant view, I added a twig field to be able to show it

```
<p>People</p>
      {% for value in restaurant.people.values %}
          <p>{{ value }}</p>
      {% endfor %}
```

But then the value that was entered in the form, doesn'tshow up in the view. It is right in the database, but the view itself doesn't let me see it even with the twig.

here is my database with the `People` entity

[image]

I think I missed something somewhere. Can you help me find the problem?

Thank you

Comment: what's the relation between restaurant and people ? Also, in your formtype, you seems to have the field `value` but in your template you call `people.values` (additionnal s). Finally, the error say that you are attempting to convert an array to a string, so you should dump your value to see how it's looks like `{{ dump(restaurant.people.values) }}`

Comment: Hi @mickdev The relation in my entity restaurant to people is `oneToMany` here is the annotation I have in my entity `* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\People", mappedBy="restaurant")` the dump show me this `[ ]` so I assume its giving an array

Comment: Also, when I get values with an `s` with symfony autocomplete. `value` actually doesn't work. So I guess `{{ restaurant.people.values }}` works

Comment: Nobody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

So in fact, you have an array. To resolve your issue, you can try to display your data in for loop

```
{% for value in restaurant.people.values %}
        {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

I think you are expecting a single value. If that's the case, you should check your entities relations to figure out why you are getting an array.
To display only the first value, here is a ugly workaround with slice

```
 {% for value in restaurant.people.values[:1] %}
        {{ value }}
 {% endfor %}
```

If you want sum all the values, you try that :

```
 {% set sum = 0 %}

 {% for value in restaurant.people.values[:1] %}
        {% set sum = sum + value %}
 {% endfor %}
```

At least, the above solutions will suppress your error.

Comment: your method works! :) but I cannot see the value in my `show.html.twig` once I submitted the form. I am missing something elsewhere, maybe in the controller? in my Database the value is well in. But in the view nothing shows. But the error disappeared with your method

Comment: To answer this question, I need to see your entity mapping both for People and Restaurant. The controller seems to work as the value is in database.

Comment: inside people entity`* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Restaurant", inversedBy="retrocessions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id", referencedColumnName="id")` and inside restaurant entity `* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\people", mappedBy="restaurant")`
     these are annotations

Comment: And how the values field looks like ?

Comment: I just have this showing in the view `<p>People who can eat</p>` the title. I don't see the value entered and the loop seems to work because I have no error but doesn't seems to show anything

Comment: I mean, in People entity, you have a field values, right ?

Comment: Yes, it is called `value DOUBLE` in my database. DOUBLE stands for a float in SQL. This is what it shows in the database, and in my entity. I updated my post to include your answer and a screenshot of my people entity

Comment: so you must have something like `/**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(name="values", type="float")
     */
    private $values;`. I ask because you seems to have an array for that field instead of number (decimal or not).

Comment: Yes right, I have this `/**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="float")
     */
    private $value;` but value is without an `s` in my entity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137834/discussion-between-mickdev-and-criss-cross).